# prevent geocomplete from returning street address from lat lng coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation, geocomplete

When I pass a lat and lng coordinate to geocomplete how do I prevent it from displaying the street portion of the address:

When I pass these coordinates to geocomplete:

```
var lat = '40.7127744'
var lng = '-74.006059';

var lat_and_long = lat + ', ' + lng ;
$("#location").geocomplete("find", lat_and_long);
```

it returns:

```
New York City Hall, City Hall Park, New York, NY 10007, USA
```

How do I restrict it to:

```
New York, NY, United States
```

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that this is possible? What reason do you have for wanting *less* information than is available? It is clearly simple to ignore the parts of the returned string that don't interest you. Are you hoping that asking for less accurate data will be faster, or is it a privacy issue that worries you?

Comment: Privacy concerns...when using geocomplete to enter a location it displays just the city and state but when looking up an address based on lat/lng it returns much more.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you have setting for that...

but since it return a string.... I think this should do it.

```
str.replace(/.*,([^,]*,[^0-9,]*)[0-9]*([^,]*,[^,]*)/g, "$1$2")
```